# My sql issues Column count doesn't match value count at row 1

Tags: mysql, sql

My sql:

```
$tsqla="INSERT INTO xcal (id, date, 1sfta, 1sftb, 2sfta, 2sftb, 3sfta, 3sftb, 4sfta, 4sftb, 5sfta, 5sftb, 6sfta, 6sftb, location) VALUES ('NULL','" . $tsdate . "', '". implode("','",$date_array[$jyr.'-'.$jmnth.'-'.$jday])."','E')";
```

Which prints out like this:

```
INSERT INTO xcal (id, date, 1sfta, 1sftb, 2sfta, 2sftb, 3sfta, 3sftb, 4sfta, 4sftb, 5sfta, 5sftb, 6sfta, 6sftb, location) 
VALUES ('NULL','2010-008-31', '0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','E')
```

There are 15 columns, 15 values, why would i get the dreaded:
"Column count doesn't match value count at row 1"
Any help appreciated :D

Comment: What database is this (mySQL, SQL Server, Oracle)?   Are any fields identit fields?

Comment: also you are trying to put a string null into an id field?

Comment: mySql, yes id is being nulled as it is autoinc

Comment: Then use `NULL`, not `'NULL'`.

Comment: Are these really your field names?  You couldn't have used something more descriptive (expecially for `date`)?  Additionally, always avoid using a reserved word as a name for _anything_ in a database - it's just going to confuse people.

Comment: Why are all your numbers, and the date and a null strings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `ID` is already `auto-incremented` you can omit it in your query clause. Then you should add a `backtick`  in one of your fields which is the `date` because it is a [RESERVED word](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html) in MySQL.

```
$tsqla="INSERT INTO xcal (`date`, 1sfta, 1sftb, 2sfta, 2sftb, 3sfta, 3sftb, 
                          4sfta, 4sftb, 5sfta, 5sftb, 6sfta, 6sftb, `location`) 
        VALUES ('" . $tsdate . "', '". implode("','",
                 $date_array[$jyr.'-'.$jmnth.'-'.$jday])."','E')";
```

try this if it works. And one more thing, check also their respective data types. `INT` fields must have values with `no single quote`.

Comment: $tsqla="INSERT INTO xcal (`date`, 1sfta, 1sftb, 2sfta, 2sftb, 3sfta, 3sftb, 4sfta, 4sftb, 5sfta, 5sftb, 6sfta, 6sftb, location) VALUES ('" . $tsdate . "', '". implode("','",$date_array[$jyr.'-'.$jmnth.'-'.$jday])."','E')";

[jtt2] => INSERT INTO xcal (`date`, 1sfta, 1sftb, 2sfta, 2sftb, 3sfta, 3sftb, 4sfta, 4sftb, 5sfta, 5sftb, 6sfta, 6sftb, location) VALUES ('2010-05-31', '0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','E')

Comment: they are varchars, the '0', 14 and 14, the funny thing is i use the same statment in another part of the code:$tsqla="INSERT INTO xcal id, date, 1sfta, 1sftb, 2sfta, 2sftb, 3sfta, 3sftb, 4sfta, 4sftb, 5sfta, 5sftb, 6sfta, 6sftb, location VALUES ('','" . $tsdate . "', '". implode("','",$date_array[$jyr.'-'.$jmnth.'-'.$jday])."','0','0','0','0','X')";